# sqlopenresult' status='-239' / cognos report error

Tags: sql, db2, cognos-10, cognos-bi, cognos-8

Does anyone knows solution for the error sqlopenresult' status='-239.
I got this error while testing a cognos report.
Any help would highly appreciate !
Thank you....

Comment: What version (and platform) of Db2 are you using?

Comment: Google gets some hits..   maybe this one http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21393953

Comment: Thank you Paul for the link...